# How to clear all search results from USPTO Patent Public Search?

Tags: search

For the [USPTO Patent Public Search](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/) tool, in Advanced Search, I would like to clear all prior queries. Though I was able to delete most of them, I can't delete one of them:

Unable to Delete Query L10:"mouse AND trap" cannot be deleted because it has tagged document(s) that KWIC text for the tagged document(s) rely on.

How can I delete this? Not sure what the error means; no obvious answer [here](https://ppubs.uspto.gov/pubwebapp/static/pages/quick-reference-guides.html); the query was undeleted (i.e. still there) if I closed my browser then immediately reopened it and went to the Public Search. It was gone when I had been away from the Public Search site for a couple of hours, though.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? How to do this varies depending on your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This well may be an issue with your browser's cache file. To clear the cache varies by browser so Googling for specific instructions for your particular browser and operating system is recommended. Here is an example for [clearing the cache on Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).